# Build development/debug build with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, compilation, create-react-app

I am building a web application with a React frontend, served by a golang api layer. I don't use Javascript a ton, so I'm not super familiar with the Node build system. Is there a way to set up a script similar to `npm run build`, but which leaves debugging information intact so that I can effectively use the browser debugger?

Answer (score 2):

This has been long requested from the CRA team - see [issue #1070](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1070).  The CRA team was a bit hesitant to implement it at first, but there is now over 150 +1 votes, so I'm hopeful it will get done (please vote).  Also, that ticket contains multiple stop-gap solutions to the question.